# Can I store the result of Fetch in a global variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a JSON file that I store in my project and when i Fetch this file I want to store the result in a global variable so I can use it later whenever I want!
So my question is: is it there a way to put this data into a global variable something like this:

```
let globalData;

fetch('./../JSON.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(JsonData => {

     globalData = JsonData;

    }).catch(error => console.error)

console.log( globalData  ) // return undifined
```

Thank you!

Comment: No you can't. Last line of the code will execute before asynchronous code gets a change to initialize `globalData`

Comment: Yes you can store the JsonData but in your code it will execute before asynchronous code gets data so try this, so it don't return undefined  setTimeout(() => {
  console.log( globalData  )
}, 4000);

Comment: @Yousaf thank you yousaf, do you think there is another way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but at the time that you set the variable, you will have already called `console.log`. At the time of calling the `console.log` the variable is not yet set because first, it takes time to perform fetching; second, fetch will not block and allow for the following lines to execute without waiting for it.

If you console log from inside of the callback or create a function outside of fetch and call it, it will print as you expect it to.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, so as i undertand if I want to store it in a global var it is not possible :/

Comment: it is possible, and you do store it correctly, it's just that when you `console.log` it it's not there yet. You need to do all the login from within the callback in `.then`

Comment: You can also put your whole app in an async function and have your global state there, and just await the fetch function

Comment: I think this is what i'am going to do, will put tho whole app inside the function fetch so this way i can acces the data at anytime, thank you a lottt

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this?

```
let globalData

async function myFunction () {
  const res = await fetch('./../JSON.json')
  const data = await res.json()
  globalData = data
  console.log(globalData)
}
myFunction()
```

Comment: like this it will work if I console log inside the function but not outside, i needed to be outside :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it'll also be asyncronous. Smth like that:

```
let globalData = fetch('./../JSON.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.error)
```

log:

```
console.log( await globalData );
```

or

```
globalData.then(result => console.log(result));
```

It returns undefined on catch.